# How to check if html form of aspx page is filled or not under page load event

Tags: asp.net, forms

I have an aspx page where i have html form with two input types of text (textboxes) and one input type of submit (button). In codebehind under Page_load() method of this page, i want to check if form is submitted or not? How can i do that ? OR how can i check if textboxes are filled or not ?

Answer (score 0):

Page is already loaded so no need to check in `Page_load`.Your all controls are HTML not asp control so you validate your text box using client side script.For example `jquery`; `javascript`.Validation is complete and you have to submit your form via your form you have to use mediater like  `webservice` or `webmethod` to connect html page to database.

Comment: You are right, but under action attribute, i am Calling the same page again and want to check if submit button has been clicked or not ? or want to check if input textboxes are filled or not ? how can i do this??